# How to set border in column chart - Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can anyone help how to set border in column chart, On click each bar to set a different border and color.
Please use this Reference Code:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            states: {
                select: {
                    color: null,
                    borderWidth:5,
                    borderColor:'Blue'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts

Comment: Thank you Kannan. Do you have any fiddle kind of reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set different colors for each column in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts)

Answer (score 2):

Updating my previous [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47647262/8632727).

Here I am using Highcharts default colors by index `e.point.index` value to set borders color of column and border width is also set by index `e.point.index` value by click on each column. You can also use custom array of border width and color and access this by  `e.point.index`.

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          var chart = e.point.series.chart;
          e.point.select(true, true);
          chart.series[0].data[e.point.index].graphic.attr({
            'stroke': colors[e.point.index],
            'stroke-width': width[e.point.index],
            'fill':Highcharts.defaultOptions.colors[e.point.index],
          });
        }
      },
    }
  },
```

```js
var colors= ['#4572A7', '#AA4643', '#89A54E', '#80699B', '#3D96AE', 
   '#DB843D', '#92A8CD', '#A47D7C', '#B5CA92'];
var width=[2,5,6,8,9,3,4] ;  

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          var chart = e.point.series.chart;
          e.point.select(true, true);
          chart.series[0].data[e.point.index].graphic.attr({
            'stroke': colors[e.point.index],
            'stroke-width': width[e.point.index],
            'fill':Highcharts.defaultOptions.colors[e.point.index],
          });
        }
      },
      /*allowPointSelect: true,
      states: {
        select: {
          borderWidth: 4,
          borderColor: '#e4b0b2'
        }
      }*/
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    showInLegend: false,
    name: 'Twitter Trending',
    colorByPoint: true,
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Hi in post i have mention  how to set different color. I updated the same. Please check

Comment: Still I am not clear what you want. And what do you mean by _Bot not able to set different border color._  in my post it works

Comment: Please look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827754/how-to-add-different-color-border-in-column-highchart-like-toggle-method-onclic

Comment: I need some modification for above code:

We have column bar chart with bottom div section, It should be work as toggle method as onClick of each bar shows different color border [ background color no change ] and bottom content. And again second click it should be hide...I want like toggle option.

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotOptions.series.point.events.click` callback function to update any of the point's properties (color, border etc.).

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
        events: {
            click: function() {
            this.update({
                color: Highcharts.defaultOptions.colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 10)]
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dtdw81L7/